# Passing data from One tableview to Another

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app I have two table views. The first table view has a set number of cells.
These cells will always be the same and will never change.

See below:

[image]

The above table view will always have the 3 cells and never more.
On my server I have my API which has routes for each of these cells.

For example:

GET - myAPI/game

GET - myAPI/book

GET - myAPI/travel

And each routes send backs different data.

**What I am trying to do is that when a user clicks on a table view cell it takes them to a new table view whose cells contain the response from the API**.

Currently my 2ND table view is empty see below:

[image]

**This is what I have tried so far:**

```
 import UIKit

 class SectorListTableViewController: UITableViewController {


struct WeatherSummary {
    var id: String
}

var testArray = NSArray()
var manuArray = NSArray()

// Array of sector within our company
var selectSector: [String] = ["Game", "Book","Travel"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 80.0




    var weatherArray = [WeatherSummary]()
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "myAPI")!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    //var params = ["email":"\(emailAdd)", "password":"\(pass)"] as Dictionary<String, String>

    var err: NSError?
    //request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSArray

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {

            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")

        }
        else {

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            var newWeather = WeatherSummary(id:"")

            if let parseJSON = json {

                for weather in parseJSON {

                    if let id = weather["employeeName"] as? String{
                        println(" LOOK HERE \(id)")
                        newWeather.id = id
                    }
                }

                weatherArray.append(newWeather)

                self.testArray = parseJSON


            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")

            }


        }

    })



    task.resume()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.selectSector.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sectorList", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    if selectSector.count > 0 {

        cell.textLabel?.text = selectSector[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? BioListTableViewController {
      let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

        if let row:Int = indexPath?.row {


        destination.bioArray = testArray




            }
          }
        }
      }
```

**BIO LIST VIEW CONTROLLER CLASS CODE:**

```
import UIKit

 struct Note {

var name:String
var job:String
}


 class BioListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

private var notes = Array<Note>()

var bioArray = NSArray()
var name = String()

 var weather = NSArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("THIS IS BIO ARRAY COUNT\(bioArray.count)")
     //var weather:WeatherSummary?
    var newItem:Note = Note(name: "", job: "")

    for x in bioArray {
        if let id = x["employeeName"] as? String{
            newItem.name = id
        }
    }

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.bioArray.count ?? 0
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

   // cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

    let weatherSummary: AnyObject = bioArray[indexPath.row]

    if let id = weatherSummary["employeeName"] as? String //Dont know the exact syntax.
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = id

    }

    if let job = weatherSummary["jobTitle"] as? String {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = job

    }


    return cell
  }

 }
```

**UPDATE:**

This is what is being returned from testArray.

[image]

Comment: so your second table is inside BioListTableViewController ?

Comment: yes exactly its in BioListTableViewController class.

Comment: Then show the code for that as well. but I think there is some issue with your code, you are making web api call inside this view controller, which I think you should make on other after user selects an option.... but share your code fort that

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code

Comment: Can you confirm that self.testArray = parseJSON is called before you select a cell?

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk Yes I can confirm that.

Comment: @user2190986 so what is in that, don't you think it should make a api call after use selects an option....?

Comment: and have you checked that it returns correct results? The ones which you want to populate

Comment: @C_X Thats what I initially tried to do. I tried making the API call when the user taps on a cell. So as there are always going to be 3 cells in my First table, I said if the user taps cell 0 make API call to GET GAME and so on. But that did not work for some reason.

Comment: destination.bioArray = testArray can you confirm that this line is getting called? If so, can you confirm that on viewDidLoad of BioListTableViewController the array count is correct?

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk Yes. Currently as I am making an API request within my view did load function. I am only calling one API route which only returns that GAME data. So no matter which cell I tap on either GAME, BOOK or TRAVEL the next table view only shows the GAME data as that the only API I have made a call too. I hope that makes sense. Apologies if its confusing.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. However, if you are setting up your array correctly and in the viewDidLoad it has correct values table shouldn't be empty.

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk   I have updated my question with an image. The image shows the data being returned by testArray. The same data appears if I tap on Game, Travel or Book. In reality it should show different data. I am not sure how to make different API calls for each table cell tap / click.

Comment: @user2190986 check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you couldn't make your API calls work on cell selection is simple.

These are asynchronous calls. Which means that they will return at some point, but not necessarily soon. In fact, the design which you have now is also bad because if your internet connection is slow it might take a long time before your API loads.

Here is what you should do.

In your `BioListTableViewController` create a variable which will identify which API needs to be called (maybe it is worth making it an `enum`):

```
enum NeededAPI {
    case Game
    case Book
    case Travel
    case None
}

class BioListTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var apiThatNeedsToBeCalled:NeededAPI = .None {
        didSet {
            //check which API is set and call the function which will call the needed API
        }
    }
var bioArray = NSArray() {
    didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

What you have to do now is to move API calling logic to the `BioListTableViewController`. When user selects cell you set the correct value for the `apiThatNeedsToBeCalled`. Once you do this, code inside the `didSet` will get executed and it should call the function which calls the appropriate API.

This function is an asynchronous one so it will return whenever it finishes. When it returns, you set

`self.bioArray = results`

which triggers

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Obviously, you need an `IBOutlet` for your `tableView`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have actually learned something. Just one more question, is the enum scenario similar to "switch statement" so for example if case game run this piece of code and if case book run this piece of code?

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way to check which case you have. using switch apiThatNeedsToBeCalled{ case .Game: .....

Comment: If you don't mind could you have a look at this and see if this is correct. Apologies I am very new to iOS development. http://pastebin.com/dVBgFxgb

Comment: didSet will only get called after you set the variable. So, in prepare for segue call destination.apiThatNeecsTobeCalled = .Game. Also, I would suggest you to not paste huge code in didSet. Instead, create a function and call it from there. However, otherwise looks like a decent progress :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been a great help! Thanks for being so nice!

Answer (score 1):

Create an `IBOutlet` for `tableView` and then call `tableView.reloadData()` inside `viewWillAppear` method, and make sure `tableView` `delegate` and `dataSource` are set to `viewController` and testArray have some objects.

But I have seen some fundamental issue in your code, you should architect your code in a way when user selects some option after that you should load data from server and it would be better if you load that data inside detailVC, at the moment you are loading data in master and even before any user interaction in viewDidLoad method which I think not right. may be use never select any option and in that case you are consume user data, you should also think about that, and also it will consume memory.

**What should you do:** pass user select option to detailVC i.e BioListVC in your case, and in side that in setter method or viewWillAppear fireOff data loading call in background and show  a spinner and when you have data set it to dataSource array and call reload method on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your data have been downloaded correct before your cell was clicked, which means `self.testArray` not `nil`.

`EDIT`:
You can use a global `NSMutableDictionary` property like `testArray`, then make 3 api calls to get the 3 different datas:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *testDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
   [testDictionary setValue:testArray1 forKey:@"books"];
   [testDictionary setValue:testArray2 forKey:@"travels"];
   [testDictionary setValue:testArray3 forKey:@"anykeys"];
```

And in your segue, use `[testDictionary valueForKey:@"books"]`

Comment: I have updated my question with an image. The image shows the data being returned by testArray. The same data appears if I tap on Game, Travel or Book. In reality it should show different data. I am not sure how to make different API calls for each table cell tap / click.